# how to get option id value using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i want to get id value of option in select only using javascript.

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity" tabindex="2" onchange="calculate(this)" required autofocus>
            <option value="">Choose Your Quantity</option>
            <?php

                if($prodqty)
                {
                    foreach($prodqty as $qty)
                    {   
            ?>

            <option value="<?=$qty->discount?>"><?=$qty->quantity_from?> to <?=$qty->quantity_to?></option>

            <?php } } ?>
        </select>
```

I am already getting option value in calculate function now i also want to get value of quantity_to?> in a variable of calculate function

Comment: does this have to be vanilla javascript... would be easier using jQuery imho

Answer (score 2):

Store it as a `data-*` attribute instead of trying to parse it out of the option text.

```
<option data-to="<?=$qty->quantity_to?>" value="<?=$qty->discount?>"><?=$qty->quantity_from?> to <?=$qty->quantity_to?></option>
```

JavaScript:

```
function calculate(select){
    var quantity_to = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-to');
}
```

Comment: good non jQuery answer, I was thinking of the data attribute although with the jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate(elem) {
    var value    = elem.value;
    var quantity = elem.querySelector('option[value="'+value+'"]').textContent.split(/to\s/).pop();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v6FGR/)